# AWS Lambda (NodeJs) put item in DynamoDB with map contains dynamic keys

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want put element but my key is dynamic.

```
{ "123" : { "S" : "15/15" }, "124" : { "S" : "0/15" } }
```

`123` and `124` are any id generate

```
let id1 = uuidv1();
let id2 = uuidv1();
var params = {
    Item: {
        id:  uuidv1(),
        exercises: {id1 : "0/15", id2 : "0/15"},
        status: "in progress"
    },
        TableName: "myTablle"
};
```

but the result in data base is:

```
{ "id1" : { "S" : "15/15" }, "id2" : { "S" : "0/15" } }
```

how to replace `id1` and `id2` by the **values** of `id1` and `id2`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: @apokryfos, sorry nop

Comment: Sorry I thought `{ [id1]: { "S" : "15/15" }, [id2]: { "S" : "0/15" } }` would do what you need

Comment: @apokryfos, `{ [id1]: { "S" : "15/15" }, [id2]: { "S" : "0/15" } }` work. sorry my 1st try do not work. thank you for your reply